# A word for "doing the dishes"

Tags: single-word-requests, obscure-terms

I am bilingual and, from time to time, I realize certain words are missing in English. I just wanted to check whether there was a word for "doing the dishes."

(If anyone is curious, the word in Korean is  [sur-guh-jee] which means to do the dishes, and nothing else)

Comment: How about 'wash up'? http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/wash-up

Answer (score 3):

How about **dishwashing**?

From Dictionary.com:

> [***dishwashing***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dishwashing?s=t):
>   the act of washing dishes.

Comment: In Britain it is "washing up", unless you use a dishwasher, which some elderly people call "washing-up machines".

Comment: @WS2 Good to know. In the U.S., we often say "cleaning up" or "cleaning up the dishes". A key question is, "Who's going to clean up after dinner?" or "Who's going to do the dishes?" We call our "washing-up machines" dishwashers.

Comment: @WS2 I'm not sure that it's *only*  old people who call them 'washing-up machine'

Answer (score 1):

The word *scullery* refers to a room where certain kitchen-related tasks (including cleaning and dishwashing, but not the actual cooking) is carried out. You might find this a useful alternative but you'll need to adapt your usage to make it fit.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scullery

> noun  scul·lery \ˈskə-lə-rē, ˈskəl-rē\
>
> Popularity: Bottom 40% of words
>
> Simple Definition of scullery
>
> a room that is near the kitchen in a large and usually old house and that is used for washing dishes, doing messy kitchen tasks, etc.

I've not seen "scullery" used as a noun indicating an action. Note that "sculling" means something quite different (related to sailing).

Comment: It's hard to see how *scullery* can work given that it refers to a *room*, not an *action*, as you yourself have noted.

Comment: @RichardKayser It depends on how the original poster wishes to work it into context if he/she likes the word (I've edited to make this clear).  I thought it's a nice word with a closely related meaning which the asker may want to learn of, perhaps shelving it away for future use.

Comment: Got it. It's a good word. I just thought it was off-point. Thanks.

Comment: OP's  'I just wanted to check whether there was a word for "doing the dishes." ' makes this not suitable for an answer. It would make a comment, perhaps.